# How can I automatically update Debian Squeeze?

Tags: debian-squeeze, automatic-updates

I want my VPS to be always up-to-date with latest updates. Is there option to enable automatic updates with apt-get or some other way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a package called [unattended-upgrades](http://packages.debian.org/squeeze/unattended-upgrades) to keep your system up to date.

There's a [guide](http://www.howtoforge.com/how-to-configure-automatic-updates-on-debian-squeeze) that can help you set it up over on HowtoForge.